# How to get even thickness on a curving mesh when rotated on a different direction

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm trying to rotate the mesh to get it looking even thickness. But around the curve it looks a little bit thinner then the rest of the extruded mesh. When its time to round it off, like in the last image, it seems to distort when I attempt to extrude.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I bet you are looking for the Spin tool then Extrude to preserve the area of the section. Here is a tutorial : https://youtu.be/OcESDOixsj0?t=138

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe cut off this part, keep only the 2 tips of the pipe and select them:

[image]

Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*, tweak the values in the *Operator* box, it will keep the thickness all along the pipe:

[image]

Comment: Excellent method!